# What happens if you die in a Warfront game in RIFT?

Tags: rift

If you die in a Warfront game in RIFT, do I lose any money and how long do you have to wait when you respawn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you lose any money even if you die anywhere else, you just have to soulmend later. But in **Warfront** or in other **pvp** instance(**Conquest** f.e.) `your soul isn't being damaged` because people die a lot in Warfront and it would be kinda sad to run around with 0% soul or to have to call medic during the battle.

The **respawn time** might be sometimes different but usually it's up to `20 seconds`.
Note that you can use `soulwalking` if you really want to get up on the place you died, but I believe it's kinda waste of soulwalk.

I highly recommend just trying the Warfront(**press K**) by yourself. It's kinda fun and you don't lose anything there. You can only gain :) (unless you waste too many pots if you use any or other consumables...)